# What's the name for this star-like shape formed by joining rectangles to the edges of a (regular) polygon?

Tags: geometry, terminology, polygons

Is there a proper name for this shape - these examples are all the same, just with different 'arm' counts.

I'd describe the second one as a *cross*, but they presumably can't all be called crosses? All but the first two could qualify as an *asterisk*...

Would they be *truncated stars*? *stargons*? *x-agons*? *polystars* ? I'm thinking they have a proper name somewhere...

[image: shapes]

Comment: Maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain

Comment: @GyroGearloose I would not say that. The concept of "star domain" includes much more shapes than these ones.

Comment: @GyroGearloose Star-convex shapes are more general than this shape as this is a union of rectangles centered around an origin and equally spaced with size in accordance with the number of rectangles.

Comment: This is different than squares appended to sides of regular polygons, but I'm not sure if those have a name either.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe and @ CyclotomicField very well, but then what exactly is the definition of those shapes given by example? Of course they all look more specific, the arms of the stars being rectangles (of unspecified length) blending into the center.

Comment: I don't know if they have ever been given a formal name, but "asterisk" gets my vote, even for the 3- and 4-armed instances. (I'd go so far as to say that a rectangle counts as a "2-armed asterisk".)

Comment: Polycross, starstrix, omnistrix ,omnicross, astercross, bandaid..